# javascript object array iteration

Tags: javascript, json, loops, iteration

I have Json data like below;

```
  let data = [
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael Schumaher",
    "position": "F1 Pilot",
    "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
  }
];
```

I need to loop iterate nodes and child arrays called social.

```
let html = '';
let i;

for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

   let socArr = data[i].social;

   socArr.forEach ( function ( item ) {
     console.log( item + '/');
   });
};
```

I need to display 'name position social' in the same div, but forEach loop gives me all array data in the json document.

Comment: Your code *is* iterating over the nodes and social array. What's the final output you want?

Comment: _"but forEach loop gives me all array data"_ That is what forEach is supposed to do, iterate over each element of the array. If you only want a certain element of the array then access only that particular element, ie `socArr[1]`

Comment: I want to append all social names to a class for an icon. Also count of social arrays will be unclear it would be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate the behavior you state.  You should be able to iterate over each record (element of the array) and then iterate over its values:

```js
let data = getData();
let body = document.querySelector('body')
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()  // used for performance
let text = (str) => document.createTextNode(str)  // used to reduce/simplify code
let br = () => document.createElement('br')       // used to reduce/simplify code

data.forEach(rcd => {
  // create new div for each record
  let div = document.createElement('div')

  // iterate over record values
  for (let value of Object.values(rcd)) {
    div.appendChild(text(value))
    div.appendChild(br())
  }

  // add to fragment
  fragment.appendChild(div)
});

// add to DOM
body.appendChild(fragment);



// Data structure is placed in function so logic SO is seen first
function getData() {
  return [{
      "name": "John Doe",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael Schumaher",
      "position": "F1 Pilot",
      "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 1em
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to your question, I would assume that you only need two `div` elements. So for that scenario, I would create two statics `div` into your html `body` then feeding them with that loop. See the example below:

```js
let data = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "position": "Accountant",
        "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Michael Schumaher",
        "position": "F1 Pilot",
        "social": ["facebook", "instagram", "youtube", "pinterest"]
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = data[i].name + '<br/>' + data[i].position + '<br/>';
    let socArr = data[i].social;
    socArr.forEach ( function ( item ) {
        document.getElementById('myDiv' + (i + 1)).innerHTML += item + '<br/>';
    });
    document.getElementById('myDiv' + (i + 1)).innerHTML += '<br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1"></div>
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
```

Comment: The only difference between this and OP's is you are using forEach for both loops, either way you are going to be accessing the same things with either method.